# Polynomial Long Division for the sequence of a geometric series?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, polynomials, power-series, generating-functions

Why does polynomial long division only work for power series if the leading term of the denominator is smaller than the leading term of the numerator?

For instances I see how long division can work for $$ \frac{1}{1-3z}$$

However, Polynomial long divisions will not work for something such as $$ (\frac{1}{2-z})$$

When trying long division for $$ \frac{1}{2-z}$$, the first couple of terms I got were $$ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{4}+\frac{z^3}{8}... $$

Although by factoring $$ \frac{1}{2-z}$$ to $$ \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}2})$$ I can replace the z in the standard geometric series with $$ \frac{z}{2}$$ and then multiply each term by 1/2, I see that the correct terms are $$ \frac{1}{2} +\frac{z}{4} + \frac{z^2}{8} + \frac{z^3}{16}... $$

Why does polynomial long division not work in cases where the leading term in the denominator is larger then the leading term in the numerator?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  The answers have pointed out that it appears that "When trying long division for $1/(2-z)$" you made some sort of error.  If you're having trouble following the given answers, I would suggest including your work to show how you got the result that you did.

Answer (score 5):

Polynomial long division would work for $1/(2-z)$ if you did it right.

```
        1/2 + z/4 + ...
      -------------
2 - z ) 1
        1 - z/2
        -------
            z/2 
            z/2 - z^2/4
            -----------
```

etc

Comment: +1 for bothering to create that layout.

Comment: I'm too lazy to do it with MathJax.

Answer (score 2):

You've done the long division for $\frac1{2-z}$ wrongly:
$$1-\frac12(2-z)=\frac z2$$
$$\frac z2-\frac z4(2-z)=\frac{z^2}4$$
$$\frac{z^2}4-\frac{z^2}8(2-z)=\frac{z^3}8\cdots$$